# SDL and nasm on 64bits linux

Tags: linux, sdl, nasm

I am having trouble with nasm and ld here is what I do:

source:

```
EXTERN SDL_Init

SECTION .text
global _start

_start:
push 0x20
call SDL_Init

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

compile:

```
nasm -f elf64 sdlini.asm
```

link:

```
ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lSDL sdlini.o -o sdlini.exe
```

and here is what I get when I run sdlini.exe

```
bash: ./sdlini.exe: Accessing a corrupted shared library
```

Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: Ah, this got me too. You were linking to a 32bit library. Please mark as solved. i.e., accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

fixed it with this

```
ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lSDL sdlini.o -o sdlini.exe
```